# Why can't I use postinst to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH to my new uploaded share libraries?

Tags: opkg

I'm developing an application that I packed as .opkg format.

The data files include some self build shard libraries that my application will use; I put them in `xxxx/my-package/usr/lib/a.so`, where `xxx/my-package/` is set as my .opkg root in opkg.conf.

Then use opkg-build to create the package. In order for my app file to find the `a.so`, I want to add the `xxx/my-package/usr/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. And I want this to be done right after the installation, so I put "`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=xxx/my-package/usr/lib`" inside the postinst file.

But after I install it, when I print the 'set', instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=xxx/my-package/usr/lib`, I got `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=xxxx/my-package`. Is it because at the postinst phase the `usr/lib` subdirectory haven't been created? Or? Any suggestion how should I achieve auto `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set into my app directory after the installation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by rpath instead. Ẃorked as expected.